# Cypress allows me to keep the session and avoid logging in between specs using Electron, but not using Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, electron, cypress

I am using Cypress v12.7.0, with Chrome v112 and Electron v106. I have several test specs and I want to run them with `npx cypress run --browser chrome`. Also, I want the first test to log in the application, and then to keep the session in order to avoid logging in again in next tests and specs. For this, I am using `cy.session()` with the `cacheAcrossSpecs: true` option.

So, when I run my tests using `npx cypress open`, both with Chrome and Electron, the first spec creates the session and the following ones restore it and execute as normal, without logging in again. This is the expected behavior.

When I do it with `npx cypress run`, with Electron as default browser, it also works as expected.

However, when I do `npx cypress run --browser chrome`, this happens:

1. The first spec creates the session and it is executed as normal
2. The second spec restores the session correctly
3. The `cy.visit()` just after restoring the session takes me to the login screen, instead of the screen that should appear once logged in
4. The test fails because it is not logged in

Again, this behavior does not happen with Electron, but only with Chrome, and specifically with the `npx cypress run` option.

Comment: Did you make sure to execute `cy.visit()` after the session is created? What I want to say is that you need 2 `cy.visit`. One for log in(inside the session function) and one after it.

Comment: Yes, I have two `cy.visit()` as you say. But the problem is that it works with Electron and not with Chrome. The code I run with both browsers is the same.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: This is the function to log in, which is executed during the beforeEach. (Sorry for the format, I don't know how to improve it.):


`cy.logIn = () => {
  cy.session('username', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl') + Cypress.env('terminalUrl'), {
      timeout: Cypress.env('timeoutPageLoad')
    });
    cy.insertLogInCredentialsAndSubmit();
  });
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl') + Cypress.env('terminalUrl'));
  cy.get('[data-testid="an-id-in-main-screen"]', {
    timeout: Cypress.env('timeoutPageLoad')
  }).should('be.visible');
};`